# An implementation of an AVL tree with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, algorithm, object-oriented, tree

I've implemented an AVL tree using unique_ptr. The code has been stress-tested and there are no crashes or segmentation faults. I left the program running at night and stopped it manually the next morning and there were a couple of millions of iterations and they all were passed.

Just one note: There could be comments about member variables privacy in class Node I just would like to mention that I'm going to implement that.

Any thoughts, comments?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* parent;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    public:
        Node() : data(0) {
            parent = nullptr;
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
        }
        explicit Node(int d) : data(d),
                               parent(nullptr) {
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
        }
};

class Avl {
    private:
        size_t current_size;
        Node* root;
    private:
        int height(Node* node);
        Node* get_min(const Node* node);
        Node* inorder_successor(const Node* node);
        void add_helper(Node* parent, Node* node);
        Node* find_helper(const Node* parent_node, const Node* node);
        Node* find_helper(const Node* parent_node, const int data);
        void transplant(Node* node, Node* second_node);
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left_rotate(Node* node);
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right_rotate(Node* node);
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left_right_rotate(Node* node);
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right_left_rotate(Node* node);
        void check_balance(Node* node);
        std::unique_ptr<Node> rebalance(Node* node);
        void traverse_inorder_helper(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, std::vector<int>& out);
        void traverse_preorder_helper(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, std::vector<int>& out);
        void traverse_postorder_helper(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, std::vector<int>& out);
    public:
        Avl() : current_size(0),
                root(nullptr) {}
        ~Avl() {
            delete root;
        }
        void add(Node* node);
        void add(int data);
        Node* find(Node* node);
        Node* find(int data);
        void remove(Node* node);
        void remove(const int& data);
        void destroy();
        void traverse_inorder(std::vector<int>& out);
        void traverse_preorder(std::vector<int>& out);
        void traverse_postorder(std::vector<int>& out);
        size_t size() const {
            return current_size;
        }
        bool empty() const {
            return !(static_cast<bool>(current_size));
        }
};

int Avl::height(Node* node) {
    if(!node) {
        return 0;
    }
    int left = height(node->left.get());
    int right =  height(node->right.get());
    return std::max(left, right) + 1;
}

Node* Avl::get_min(const Node* node) {
    Node* temp = node->right.get();
    while(temp->left) {
        temp = temp->left.get();
    }
    return temp;
}

void Avl::remove(Node* node) {
    Node* successor(nullptr);
    if(!node->left) {
        transplant(node, node->right.get());
        check_balance(node);
    } else if(!node->right) {
        transplant(node, node->left.get());
        check_balance(node);
    } else {
        successor = inorder_successor(node);
        if(successor->parent != node) {
            transplant(successor, successor->right.get());
            check_balance(successor->parent);
            successor->right.release();
            successor->right.reset(node->right.get());
            if(successor->right) {
                successor->right->parent = successor;
            }
        }
        transplant(node, successor);
        successor->left.release();
        successor->left.reset(node->left.get());
        if(successor->left) {
            successor->left->parent = successor;
        }
        successor->parent = node->parent;
        check_balance(successor);
    }
}

void Avl::remove(const int& data) {
    Node* node = find(data);
    if(!node) {
        return;
    }
    Node* successor(nullptr);
    if(!node->left) {
        transplant(node, node->right.get());
        check_balance(node);
    } else if(!node->right) {
        transplant(node, node->left.get());
        check_balance(node);
    } else {
        successor = inorder_successor(node);
        if(successor->parent != node) {
            transplant(successor, successor->right.get());
            check_balance(successor->parent);
            successor->right.release();
            successor->right.reset(node->right.get());
            if(successor->right) {
                successor->right->parent = successor;
            }
        }
        transplant(node, successor);
        successor->left.release();
        successor->left.reset(node->left.get());
        if(successor->left) {
            successor->left->parent = successor;
        }
        successor->parent = node->parent;
        check_balance(successor);
    }
}

Node* Avl::find_helper(const Node* parent_node, const Node* node) {
    if(!parent_node || parent_node->data == node->data) {
        return const_cast<Node*>(parent_node);
    }
    if(node->data > parent_node->data) {
        return find_helper(parent_node->right.get(), node);
    } else if(node->data < parent_node->data) {
        return find_helper(parent_node->left.get(), node);
    }
    return nullptr;
}

Node* Avl::find_helper(const Node* parent_node, const int data) {
    if(!parent_node || data == parent_node->data) {
        return const_cast<Node*>(parent_node);
    }
    if(data > parent_node->data) {
        return find_helper(parent_node->right.get(), data);
    } else if(data < parent_node->data) {
        return find_helper(parent_node->left.get(), data);
    }
    return nullptr;
}

Node* Avl::find(Node* node) {
    return find_helper(root, node);
}

Node* Avl::find(int data) {
    return find_helper(root, data);
}

void Avl::destroy() {
    delete root;
}

void Avl::transplant(Node* node, Node* second_node) 
{
    if(!node->parent) {
        root = second_node;
    }
    if(node->parent && node->parent->right.get() == node) {
        node->parent->right.release();
        node->parent->right.reset(second_node);
    } else if(node->parent && node->parent->left.get() == node) {
        node->parent->left.release();
        node->parent->left.reset(second_node);
    }
    if(node->parent && second_node) {
        second_node->parent = node->parent;
    }
}

Node* Avl::inorder_successor(const Node* node) {
    Node* temp = const_cast<Node*>(node);
    if(temp->right) {
        return get_min(temp);
    }
    Node* parent = temp->parent;
    while(parent && temp == parent->right.get()) {
        temp = parent;
        parent = parent->parent;
    }
    return parent;
}

std::unique_ptr<Node> Avl::left_rotate(Node* node) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node);
    temp = std::move(node->right);
    node->right = std::move(temp->left);
    temp->left.reset(node);
    if(node->right.get()) {
        node->right->parent = node;
    }
    temp->parent = node->parent;
    Node* temp_raw = temp.release();
    if(node->parent) {
        if(node == node->parent->left.get()) {
            Node* npl = node->parent->left.release();
            npl = temp_raw;
            node->parent->left.reset(npl);
        } else if(node == node->parent->right.get()) {
            Node* npr = node->parent->right.release();
            npr = temp_raw;
            node->parent->right.reset(npr);
        }
    }
    node->parent = temp_raw;
    return std::unique_ptr<Node>(temp_raw);
}

std::unique_ptr<Node> Avl::right_rotate(Node* node) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node);
    temp = std::move(node->left);
    node->left = std::move(temp->right);
    temp->right.reset(node);
    if(node->left.get()) {
        node->left->parent = node;
    }
    temp->parent = node->parent;
    Node* temp_raw = temp.release();
    if(node->parent) {
        if(node == node->parent->left.get()) {              
            Node* npl = node->parent->left.release();
            npl = temp_raw;
            node->parent->left.reset(npl);
        } else if(node == node->parent->right.get()) {
            Node* npr = node->parent->right.release();
            npr = temp_raw;
            node->parent->right.reset(npr);
        }
    }
    node->parent = temp_raw;       
    return std::unique_ptr<Node>(temp_raw);
}

std::unique_ptr<Node> Avl::left_right_rotate(Node* node) {
    Node* left = node->left.release();
    node->left = std::move(left_rotate(left));
    return right_rotate(node);

}

std::unique_ptr<Node> Avl::right_left_rotate(Node* node) {
    Node* right = node->right.release();
    node->right = std::move(right_rotate(right));
    return left_rotate(node);
}

void Avl::add_helper(Node* parent, Node* node) {
    if(node->data > parent->data) {
        if(!parent->right.get()) {
            parent->right.reset(node);
            node->parent = parent;
            ++current_size;
        } else {                
            add_helper(parent->right.get(), node);
        }
    } else if(node->data < parent->data) {
        if(!parent->left.get()) {
            parent->left.reset(node);
            node->parent = parent;
            ++current_size;
        } else {
            add_helper(parent->left.get(), node);
        }

    } else {
        return;
    }
    check_balance(node);
    return;
}

void Avl::add(Node* node) {
    if(!root) {
        root = node;
        return;
    }
    add_helper(root, node);
}

void Avl::add(int data) {
    if(!root) {
        root = new Node(data);
        return;
    }        
    Node* node = new Node(data);
    add_helper(root, node);
}

void Avl::check_balance(Node* node) {
    int left = height(node->left.get());
    int right = height(node->right.get());
    if(left - right > 1 || left - right < -1) {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> uptr = std::move(rebalance(node));
        node = uptr.release();
    } 
    if(!node->parent) {
        return;
    }
    check_balance(node->parent);
}

std::unique_ptr<Node> Avl::rebalance(Node* node) {
    int left = height(node->left.get());
    int right = height(node->right.get());
    std::unique_ptr<Node> uptr = std::unique_ptr<Node>();
    if(left - right > 1) {
        if(height(node->left->left.get()) >= height(node->left->right.get())) {
            uptr = std::move(right_rotate(node));
        } else {
            uptr = std::move(left_right_rotate(node));
        }

    }
    left = height(node->left.get());
    right = height(node->right.get());
    if(left - right < -1) {
        if(height(node->right->right.get()) >= height(node->right->left.get())) {
            uptr = std::move(left_rotate(node));                
        } else {
            uptr = std::move(right_left_rotate(node));
        }
    }       
    if(!uptr->parent) {
        root = uptr.release();
        return std::unique_ptr<Node>(root);
    }
    return uptr;
}

void Avl::traverse_inorder(std::vector<int>& out) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root_ptr(root);
    traverse_inorder_helper(root_ptr, out);
    root = root_ptr.release();
}

void Avl::traverse_preorder(std::vector<int>& out) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root_ptr(root);
    traverse_preorder_helper(root_ptr, out);
    root = root_ptr.release();
}

void Avl::traverse_postorder(std::vector<int>& out) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root_ptr(root);
    traverse_postorder_helper(root_ptr, out);
    root = root_ptr.release();
}

void Avl::traverse_inorder_helper(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, std::vector<int>& out) {
    if(!node) {
        return;
    }
    traverse_inorder_helper(node->left, out);
    out.push_back(node->data);
    traverse_inorder_helper(node->right, out);
}

void Avl::traverse_preorder_helper(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, std::vector<int>& out) {
    if(!node) {
        return;
    }
    out.push_back(node->data);
    traverse_preorder_helper(node->left, out);
    traverse_preorder_helper(node->right, out);
}

void Avl::traverse_postorder_helper(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, std::vector<int>& out) {
    if(!node) {
        return;
    }
    traverse_postorder_helper(node->left, out);
    traverse_postorder_helper(node->right, out);
    out.push_back(node->data);
}
```

Here is a given a minimal version of the stress-test code. As a golden has been used rosetta-avl:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "../src/mset.hpp"
#include "../shared_src/avl.h"

int generate_random_int(int min, int max) {
    return min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
}

void generate_random_vector(std::vector<int>& out, const int min, 
        const int max, const size_t max_size) {
    size_t size = generate_random_int(0, max_size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {  
        int num = generate_random_int(min, max);
        out.push_back(num);
    }
}

void show(const std::vector<int>& out) {
    for(int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << out[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void init_sets(Avl* set, AVLtree<int>* set_golden, int min, int max, size_t max_size) {
    std::vector<int> out;
    generate_random_vector(out, min, max, max_size);   
    for(auto const& item : out) {
        set->add(item);
        set_golden->insert(item);
    }
    if(!out.empty()) {
        size_t random_index = generate_random_int(0, out.size() - 1);
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "The initial vector:\n\t";
        show(out);
#endif
        set->remove(out[random_index]);
        set_golden->deleteKey(out[random_index]);
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "The removed element:\n\t";
        std::cout << out[random_index] << "\n";
#endif
    }
}

bool stress_test(const int min, const int max, const size_t max_size) {
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {  
        Avl* set = new Avl();
        AVLtree<int>* set_golden = new AVLtree<int>();
        std::cout << "##############################################" << "\n";
        init_sets(set, set_golden, min, max, max_size);
        std::vector<int> out;
        //set->traverse_preorder(out);
        set->traverse_postorder(out);
        std::vector<int> out_golden;
        //set_golden->preorder(out_golden);
        set_golden->postorder(out_golden);
        if(out == out_golden) {
            std::cout << "PASS\n ";
        } else {
            std::cout << "FAIL\n ";
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "\tout: ";
        show(out);
        std::cout << "\tgolden: ";
        show(out_golden);
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "##############################################" << "\n";
        delete set;
        delete set_golden;
        std::cout << "Iteration: " << i << "\n";
        ++i;        
    }  
    return 0;
}

int main() {    
    int result = stress_test(0, 1000000000, 1000);  
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a test case, showing this code in action?

Comment: dfhwze - I've added a test case. Please see the below-given code.

Answer (score 6):

## Prefer default member initialization

You can use default [member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) to avoid repeating common initialization in the constructors. Also, `std::unique_ptr` will already initialize itself, there is no need to do this explicitly. So:

```
class Node {
        int data{};
        Node* parent{};
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;

    public:
        Node() = default;
        explicit Node(int d) : data(d) {}
};
```

## Move `class Node` inside `class Avl`

Class `Node` is just an implementation detail of `Avl`. Move it inside `class Avl`, this will also avoid polluting the global namespace with the very generic name `Node`. This might require you to write `Avl::Node` in some places. So:

```
class Avl {
public:
    class Node {
        ...
    };

    ...
};
```

## Make member functions that do not modify the tree `const`

This helps the compiler generate better code, and will let the compiler report an error if you accidentily do modify any of the member variables of `Avl`. For example, `height()` doesn't modify the tree, so it should be marked `const`:

```
int height(const Node* node) const;
```

There are many more functions that can be made `const`. You do seem to know about this because you did it for `size()` and `empty()`.

## Avoid unnecessary initialization

Initializing a `std::unique_ptr` with a default constructed temporary is redundant. Instead of:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> uptr = std::unique_ptr<Node>();
```

Just write:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> uptr;
```

## Use `std::make_unique` to construct new `Node`s

You can avoid manual calls to `new` and repeating types by using `auto` and [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). For exampe, instead of writing:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node);
```

You can write:

```
auto temp = std::make_unique<Node>();
```

## Make use of `std::unique_ptr`'s automatic pointer moving functionality

I see you use `release()` and `reset()` a lot, but instead of manually releasing pointers, you can make use of the fact that assigning one `std::unique_ptr` will do all these tasks automatically for you. For example, instead of:

```
successor->right.release();
successor->right.reset(node->right.get());
```

You can just write:

```
successor->right.reset(node->right.get());
```

The call to `reset()` already implies that it will release the old pointer. Furthermore, instead of:

```
Node* temp_raw = temp.release();
Node* npl = node->parent->left.release();
npl = temp_raw;
node->parent->left.reset(npl);
```

You can write:

```
node->parent->left = std::move(temp);
```

Since the [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) will take care of releasing correctly for both the left and right hand side. You can also do this in a `return` statement. So instead of:

```
root = uptr.release();
return std::unique_ptr<Node>(root);
```

Just write:

```
return std::move(uptr);
```

Finally, you can also use [`std::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/swap2) if you need to swap two `std::unique_ptr`s, so instead of:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node);
temp = std::move(node->right);
node->right = std::move(temp->left);
temp->left.reset(node);
```

You can write:

```
auto temp = std::make_unique<Node>();
std::swap(node->right, temp->left);
```

## Consider avoiding signed integers for things that cannot be negative

You store the height as an `int`. However, a negative height for an AVL tree does not make sense. You could make it an `unsigned int` instead. This does mean a little care is necessary, for example instead of:

```
if(left - right > 1 || left - right < -1) {
```

You should write:

```
if(left > right + 1 || right > left + 1) {
```

On the other hand, it's only used internally, using `unsigned int` might actually introduce a bug if you don't take care of wraparound if you subtract values, and the height is only ever a very small value, so this is just me being very pedantic.

## Expose iterators for tree traversal

The functions for traversing the tree are particularly bad. They force the use of a `std::vector` that will contain a copy of all the data, which wastes memory and potentially time if not all elements are going to be necessary. Also, ideally you would want to write something like this:

```
Avl tree;
...
for (auto &item: tree.pre_order()) {
    std::cout << item << ", ";
}
```

This would require you to write `class`es that represents the in-order, pre-order and post-order views of the tree, and each of these classes would contain a `begin()` and `end()` member function that return iterators that will iterate in the given order. I would also make the `Avl` class itself expose `begin()` and `end()` that do in-order traversal, so you get the items in sorted order, as you would expect from a `std::set` for example.

## Consider making it look more like a STL container

You already have some member function names that are the same as those used in STL containers, such as `empty()`, `size()`, and `remove()`. Some others can be renamed to match the STL naming conventions:

- `add()` -> insert()`
- `destroy()` -> `clear()`

Also consider adding functions from [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), such as `equal_range()`, `lower_bound()`, and so on. Furthermore, add a constructor that takes an initializer list of elements to add to the tree, so you can write:

```
Avl tree{3, 6, 2, 9};
```

## Consider making this a `template`

Your AVL tree can only store `int`s. Consider making it a template, so you can store different types, and perhaps have a different comparison function as well.